# Is it possible to explicitly tell a script when to execute, when the page is open dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page which dynamically opens each page based upon the  tags. I am attempting to execute a script, which is to run when the dynamic page is run from the div id="CreateVids" tag.

I'm totally new to this so i'm not too sure what is the problem. I have been looking to see if there is a property of the  that I can set but I cannot seem to find it.

Any help would be much appreciated! 
Thanks a lot!

Sorry Treffynnmon, yes I do have some code

```
<body>
    <div id="about" class="selectable">
                <p>Developed by Jacob Bowe</p>
                <p><br /><br /><a href="#" class="grayButton goback">Close</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="Demo">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>Demonstration Video</h1>
            <a class="back" href="#home">Home</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="rounded">
            <center><video id="video1" src="bunny.mp4" width="270" height="180" controls></video></center>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div id="CreateVids">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>Create your own film!</h1>
            <a class="back" href="#">Home</a>
        </div>
        <h2>Put the film clips in any order! Click on proceed to view</h2>
        <ul class="rounded">
            <li><video id="vid1" src="bunny.mp4" width="90" height="60" onClick="test()" class="draggable"></video>
            <video id="vid2" src="bunny.mp4" width="90" height="60" class="draggable"></video>
            <video id="vid3" src="bunny.mp4" width="90" height="60" class="draggable"></video></li>
            <li><video id="vid4" src="bunny.mp4" width="90" height="60" class="draggable"></video>
            <video id="vid5" src="bunny.mp4" width="90" height="60" class="draggable"></video>
            <video id="vid6" src="bunny.mp4" width="90" height="60" class="draggable"></video></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="rounded">
            <div id="dropbox1" class="drop"></div>
            <div id="dropbox2" class="drop"></div>
            <div id="dropbox3" class="drop"></div>
            <div id="dropbox4" class="drop"></div>
            <div id="dropbox5" class="drop"></div>
            <div id="dropbox6" class="drop"></div>
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

The pages are loaded dynamically, so the first loads "about" and the second loads "CreateVids"

The page is being run from a JQuery function

```
$('#pageevents').
                    bind('pageAnimationStart', function(e, info){ 
                        $(this).find('.info').append('Started animating ' + info.direction + '&hellip; ');
                    }).
                    bind('pageAnimationEnd', function(e, info){
                        $(this).find('.info').append(' finished animating ' + info.direction + '.<br /><br />');
```

I want to load the script when the "CreateVids" is loaded into the browser. The idea is that I can select the "draggable" class on the video tags and drag them using JQuery.

Any ideas will really be appreciated, 
Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, but the above does not really make much sense or describe the problem in enough depth. Do you have any code? Any more information that could make this easier to understand?

Comment: does anyone else have any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the required script in a `function`, and call it inside `pageAnimationEnd` using an `if` (or a `switch`) to check for the correct page (or if the page changer `switch` is of your own, you can call it right there).